# PHP Changing Debug Trace size / Magento trace

Tags: debugging, magento, stack-trace

I commonly deal with troubleshooting Magento and have found that the traces provide good information, but tend to be quite short.

I do not know the Magento internals but I believe it's related to the PHP `debug_backtrace` functionality?

If this is the case how can I change the size of an output trace for an error that I am able to reproduce? Is there a high level setting to change (such as using `ini_set`) or does this require the editing of core code?

Comment: What do yo mean by "short traces"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about the 2nd argument, then unfortunately there's no easy way to do this. `debug_backtrace` function is called in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php::mageDebugBacktrace` with no arguments. So the only way to change it is copy the complete file into `app/code/local/Mage/Core/functions.php` and modify it as you need. However this practice has some negative effects and not encouraged to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Short Version: You can't with something like xDebug, and it will be really slow.

The logged exceptions don't contain a full "trace" of the code.  Out of the box PHP doesn't keep track of this information.  The output that `debug_backtrace` returns is [a call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).  A call stack returns the function/method calls it took to reach the current **depth**.  For example

```
function a(){
    b();
    c();
}

function c()
{
    d();
}

function d()
{
    //DEBUG HERE
}

//start program
a();
```

If you got a call stack at the `//DEBUG HERE` function, you'd get

```
a();
c();
d();
```

The function `b()` wouldn't be included, because it's already been called.  **This** is the only information PHP is able to return.  A full backtrace would contain an insane amount of information, and performance would grind to a halt.

If you want a full function trace, you'll need to install an extension like xDebug, and use it's [tracing features](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace). However, this won't be suitable for a production store, there's just too much information to track.

Comment: +1 xDebug for function tracing.  Slow as molasses but twice as useful on occasion.